# GitHub Repository issue

Tags: html, css, github, repository

I had github hosting my code for a blog i created to help apply what i was learning. It recently stopped hosting my code, and im not exactly sure why. It started messing up when i linked my github desktop app to my account (maybe something to do with it)? after some trial and error (mostly error) i created a new account and tried to reupload it and it worked fine with no issue. has anyone experienced something similar?

i tried deleting the reuploading the whole repirstory. I created another version of the files, and tried uploading those as well. Only when i just created a new account, did it work.

Comment: This is a question best answered by github support. Which is in a different castle. You may also want to check the email address associated with the previous account. Or if github nuked your account without letting you know why, you may want to consider some alternative code hosting service instead.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.